# Why do I get IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

**The exercise question:**

Create the method `lengths` that gets a list of String variables as a parameter and returns an ArrayList that contains the lengths of the Strings in the same order as the original list.

The output of the given objects should be:
`The lengths of the Strings: [5, 3, 10, 27]`

**My code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LengthsOfStrings {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> lengths(ArrayList<String> list) {
        ArrayList<Integer> lengthList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        int count = 0;
        
        for (String word : list) {
            for (int x = 0; x < ( list.get(x) ).length(); x++) {
                count++;
            }
            lengthList.add(count);
            count = 0;
        }
        return lengthList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Ciao");
        list.add("Moi");
        list.add("Benvenuto!");
        list.add("badger badger badger badger");
        ArrayList<Integer> lengths = lengths(list);
        
        System.out.println("The lengths of the Strings: " + lengths);
        
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
> 4, Size: 4
>
> ... at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
> at LengthsOfStrings.lengths(LengthsOfStrings.java:11)
> at LengthsOfStrings.main(LengthsOfStrings.java:26)

Comment: Without line numbers, it's a little hard to tell what's going on here, but keep in mind: Java uses [zero indexing](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-array-indexes-start-with-0-zero-in-many-programming-languages) meaning that the **first** element in a list or array is at index **zero**. Therefore, a list of length 4 will have indices 0, 1, 2, and 3, but index 4 will be out of bounds, as index 4 would be the *fifth* element in the list of four elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said in another answer you just use `length()` method, but as for the error you faced is because `list` does not have the index `x` as `x` is the length of string,  which in your test cases is more than 3 like "Benvenuto!"

Fix this

```
for (String word : list) {
    for (int x = 0; x < ( list.get(x) ).length(); x++) {
```

to

```
for (String word : list) {
    for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) {
```